# How to calculate the PDF of a modified random variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function

I have a random variable X that has a PDF defined by the following piecewise function:
$$f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        x + 1 & \text{if } x \in \left[-1, 0\right]\\
        -x + 1 & \text{if } x \in \left[0, 1\right]\\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

Basically, this PDF creates a triangle with a base of length 2 (from -1 to 1), and a height of 1 (such that the area under the curve is 1, by the rules of PDFs)

I've plotted it with matplotlib here:
[image]

I am trying to better understand how modifications to a random variable with this sort of function defining its PDF work. For example, if we defined $Y = 2X - 1$, I understand that the area under the curve for Y will still need to be 1 to be a valid PDF. I also understand that the domain of Y will be $[-3, 1]$. However, how does this affect the new height of the RV Y?

More generally, if you had an arbitrary PDF $f(x)$, and you were to apply some linear transformation to it, how does that affect the domain and range, generally?
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The CDF of $X$ is $F_X(x) = P(X\leq x)$. The CDF of $Y$ is $F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y)$. Now, $$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(2X-1 \leq y) = P\left(X \leq \frac{y+1}{2}\right) = F_X\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right).$$ Since the pdf is the derivative of the CDF, can you differentiate both sides of the above equation to find the pdf of $Y$ in terms of the pdf of $X$? Don't forget the chain rule for differentiation!

Comment: So I went for a slightly different approach - I instead tried to integrate the piecewise PDF, and got the following results:
$$F_{X}(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{8}\left(y^2 + 6y + 5\right)& \text{if } x \in [-1, 0]\\
        \frac{1}{8}\left(-y^2 + 2y + 3\right) & \text{if } x \in [0, 1]
    \end{cases}$$

I did this by taking the $\frac{y + 1}{2}$ term that you identified in your comment, and plugging into x for the PDF

Comment: Is this on the right track? I am unable to edit my previous comment

Comment: I have no idea what you are calculating or what your formulas mean since the variable on one side is $x$ and on the other $y$ but the conditions are in terms of $x$. The whole purpose of my hint was to suggest to you that **without calculating any formulas for CDFs**, the equation $F_Y(y)=F_X\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)$ could be differentiated w.r.t. $y$ on both sides to yield $f_Y(y)=\frac 12f_X\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)$. I wish you all the best in future attempts to solve the problem.